# SELENIUM JS - driver.getTitle() return false even if the condition is met

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to develop a small selenium js script to do some checking. The objective of this script is to return a message to the console whether the user is logged in or not. To check the connection I use a driver.getTitle () the title of the page is the same as that of my condition is however it always returns me false

```
     
        var promise = driver.getTitle().then(function(titre) {
            if (titre == "Mon compte")
            {
                console.log('Status Connexion  : ✅');
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Status Connexion : ❎');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

If anyone has an idea I am interested because I do not see or can be my mistake.